# error when sending mail using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am getting the below error when I try to send mail

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mx.google.com ESMTP ej10sm2084527pdb.35 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SMTP: EHLO localhost
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250-mx.google.com at your service, [182.64.29.228]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SMTP: AUTH LOGIN
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ej10sm2084527pdb.35 - gsmtp
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH command failed: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ej10sm2084527pdb.35 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SMTP: QUIT
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:221 2.0.0 closing connection ej10sm2084527pdb.35 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed.
SMTP connect() failed.
```

Comment: Please show your code?

Comment: yeah sure. you can check in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094401/how-to-send-mail-from-the-redirected-page-of-an-ajax-in-php

Comment: Pls help as i have to submit my project my monday

Comment: Make sure you're using latest PHPMailer (5.2.10).

Comment: File name "class-phpmailer.php". I have copied this file from wp-Includes folder to my folder and then calling it like this "require_once("class-phpmailer.php");" . I just hope - if this is the correct way of using this file.

Comment: i am using this Version 5.2.7

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your code, my best guess is, add this to your code:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'
```

Note: Please adapt this code to yours.

Comment: you can see my code in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094401/how-to-send-mail-from-the-redirected-page-of-an-ajax-in-php

Comment: i have already tried that but it was not working. Showing the error : SMTP connect() failed.